# JFrame not displaying contents

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, handler

I know this question has been asked a lot, but ive read through about 10 different articles, all reccomending to different things such as "frame = this" nad frame.add(d)" Im not sure why, but none of these have been working. I typed something and the program worked fine, except the Jbuttons wouldnt show up until i clicked on the JFrame a few times. After some tweaking of that code, im back to the start. Now i just get a error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Guis.Dynamic_JFrame.<init>(Dynamic_JFrame.java:37)
at Guis.Dynamic_JFrame.main(Dynamic_JFrame.java:46)
```

Heres my code:

```
public class Dynamic_JFrame extends JFrame{

static JFrame frame;
Graphics g;
Handler handler = new Handler();

JButton red = new JButton();
JButton green = new JButton();
JButton orange = new JButton();

public Dynamic_JFrame(){

    red.setText("RED");
    green.setText("GREEN");
    orange.setText("orange");

    add(green);
    add(red);
    add(orange);

    red.addActionListener(handler);
    green.addActionListener(handler);
    orange.addActionListener(handler);

    frame.setVisible(true);

}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Dynamic_JFrame d = new Dynamic_JFrame();
    frame = new JFrame("Changing colors");
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
    frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(500,500));
    frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(500,500));
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public class Handler implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource()==red){
            getContentPane().setBackground(Color.RED);
        }
        if(e.getSource()==green){
            getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        }
        if(e.getSource()==orange){
            getContentPane().setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        }
    }

}


}
```

New code, Minor Changes. Program works as intended except for the buttons not updating until i click where they should be:

```
JFrame frame;

public Dynamic_JFrame(){

    frame = new JFrame();
    frame = this;

    red.setText("RED");
    green.setText("GREEN");

    frame.add(green);
    frame.add(red);

    frame.setVisible(true);

}

    public static void main(String[] args){
    Dynamic_JFrame d = new Dynamic_JFrame();
    d.frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
    d.frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(500,500));
    d.frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(500,500));
    d.frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    d.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    d.frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
}
```

Comment: The `NullPointerException` comes from calling `frame.setVisible( true )` in your constructor, while `frame` is still `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A number of things...

Firstly, `Dynamic_JFrame` extends from `JFrame` so I don't know why you've then gone and create another frame...

Secondly, when `Dynamic_JFrame` calls `frame.setVisible` in the constructor, `frame` is `null` as it has not being initialised.

From my perspective, the simplest solution would be to extend `Dynamic_JFrame` from something like `JPanel` instead and simply add it to an instance of `JFrame`

For example...

```
public class Dynamic_JFrame extends JPanel {

static JFrame frame;
// Not sure that this is a good idea...
Graphics g;

//...

public Dynamic_JFrame(){

    // Don't use this...
    //frame.setVisible(true);

}

public static void main(String[] args){
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Dynamic_JFrame d = new Dynamic_JFrame();
            frame = new JFrame("Changing colors");
            frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            frame.add(d);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This will occur if you make the frame visible before you've added anything to it.  Typically, you should prepare the UI before making it visible or call `revalidate` and `repaint` on the frame/content pane...

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I made the class extend JPanel, and i got the code to work properly, except now i cant call getContentPane().setBackground(); I tried frame.setBackground() but that didn't work. Ive also tried to repaint() and revalidate() after a color change but nothing, Thanks.

Comment: +1 @DrewWood please update your question with the changes you have made, so we could better understand

Comment: Sorry, i need to wait 8 hours to answer my question, I do have the code all fixed and working. The main thing was changing the "extends JFrame" to "extends JPanel". I will post the code in the answer section as soon as i can.